# Changing (Corrupt) matrix value in Matlab randomly

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

I have matrix like below;

```
x1(1,:)=[0.1,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.1, 0.9,0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9, 0.9,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.9, 0.9,0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9, 0.1,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.1];
```

and I want to corrupt that pattern with a given specific percentage. For instance, if I want to corrupt pattern %8 then 2 elements of matrix has to be changed (if the element is 0.9, it should be 0.1 and vice versa).

For matrix bleow;

```
x(:,1)=[-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,
   -1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,
    -1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1]';
```

I have tried this function and it works fine.

```
function Ret=corrupt(Inx,per)

    I_SIZE=length(Inx);
    N_COR=floor(I_SIZE*per/100);

    I_INX=randperm(I_SIZE);
    C_INX=I_INX(1:N_COR);
    Inx(C_INX)= -1 * Inx(C_INX);

    Ret=Inx;
```

How can I make changes for 0.1 and 0.9?

Comment: Great.  What have you tried?

Comment: I wrote what i have tried.

Comment: I think you need to do this - `Inx(C_INX)= 1-Inx(C_INX);` and rest of the code stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier using [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
C_INX = randsample(1:I_SIZE, N_COR);
Inx(C_INX) = 1-Inx(C_INX);
```